# Ordering with one minimal element, but without the smallest element

Tags: relations

What can be the example of an ordering with one minimal element, but without the smallest element? Can this be an example: Proper subset relation defined on the set {{1}, {1,2}}.

Answer (score 6):

If $P$ is a finite partial order, and $p\in P$, there is always a minimal element $q\le p$. Thus, if a finite partial order has exactly one minimal element, that element is automatically the smallest element of the partial order. Thus, if you want a partial order with exactly one minimal element and no smallest element, you’ll need an infinite partial order. Here’s the Hasse diagram of one that works:

```
        °       *  
                |  
                *  
                |  
                *  
                |  
                ·  
                ·  
                ·
```

The element $\circ$ in the upper left is the unique minimal element, and there is clearly no smallest element. A slightly more interesting example:

```
                *  
              / |  
             °  *  
                |  
                *  
                |  
                ·  
                ·  
                ·
```

Comment: I don't understand your diagram. For example. in the first diagram, isn't the upper most start a minimal element?

Comment: @SungheeYun: None of the stars in either diagram is a minimal element: each has other elements strictly below it. The only element in either diagram that has no other elements strictly below it is the circle.

Comment: Got you! This is indeed great illustration of the examples. Thanks, Brian!

Comment: @SungheeYun: You’re welcome!

Comment: just upvoted your answer :)

Comment: this answer is super useful, but a warning to beginners like myself: this discussion assumes that a p.o. is by definition reflexive. I am reading a book now in which a p.o. is merely transitive and anti-symmetric. With this book's definition, I think the first claim would have to read "If $P$ is a finite p.o. and $p \in P$, there is always a minimal element $q$". Aha, but despite this, your second claim holds even under my definition. Ok i feel better now. Even with my def., there can be no finite-sized example.

Comment: @311411: What your book calls a partial order is in my experience more often called a *strict* partial order; the term *partial order* most often refers to my kind.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott As an example, given $\mathbb{N} = \{0,1,2,...\}$ and $Y=\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ with $\subset$, does $E = \{\mathbb{N}, \mathbb{N}\setminus \{0\}, \mathbb{N}\setminus \{1\}, \mathbb{N}\setminus \{1,2\}, \mathbb{N}\setminus \{1,2,3\}...\}$ work? :)

Comment: @nolemonnomelon: Yes: its Hasse diagram looks like my second eample.

Answer (score 2):

You will need a partially, not totally ordered, set to get an example. You may take a (silly) example like: $$\{(0,y)\in {\Bbb R}^2: 0<y<1\} \cup \{(1,y)\in {\Bbb R}^2: 0\leq y<1\}$$
with the partial ordering $(x,y) \prec (x',y')$ iff $x=x'$ and $y\leq y'$. Then $(1,0)$ is a minimal element but not a smallest element (because it is not related to the elements with $x=0$) and there are no other minimal elements.

Comment: @Rugh ingenius example!